# Android Java handler post delay at each records in loop

Tags: java, javascript, android, loops, handler

I was having some problem when trying to do the animation like setTimeout() in Android Java. I have a list of geometries and I wanted to plot them onto map one at a time:

```
public void getDirection(Event eventModel, final Context context) {
    String eventX = eventModel.getEventX();
    String eventY = eventModel.getEventY();

    //Code to get data geometry data from API and store in pathGeometries       
    final Drawable d = EventDrawableImage.resizeCurrentLocImage("current_loc",
            context);
    for (int iii = 0; iii < pathGeometries.size(); iii++) {
        final int counter = iii ;
            EventDetail.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                private long time = 0;
                public void run()
                {
                    time += 1000;
                    EventDetail.handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

                    moveNext(pathGeometries.get(counter).getX(),
                            pathGeometries.get(counter).getY(), 0, d);
                }
            }, 1000); 
    }
}

public static void moveNext(double coordx, double coordy, int k, Drawable d){
    //EventMain.mMapView.removeAll();

    // Set center
    Point p = new Point(coordx, coordy);
    EventMain.mMapView.zoomToResolution(p, 1);

    // Add marker
    PictureMarkerSymbol graphicIcon;
    graphicIcon = new PictureMarkerSymbol(d);
    Symbol symbol = graphicIcon;
    HashMap<String, Object> attrMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    attrMap.put("currentLoc", "User Current location");

    EventMain.graphicsLayer.addGraphic(new Graphic(p, symbol, attrMap));     
}
```

The problem that I was having now is at each point from pathGeometries passing into moveNext(), it does not hold for 20 seconds before moving to another point. Instead, it just loop all the way until the end without stopping at each point.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you are using  for `loop` ? to achieve required behavior only use `Handler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the intention correctly, but try something like this:

```
long time = 0;
for (int iii = 0; iii < pathGeometries.size(); iii++) {
    final int counter = iii;
    time += 1000;
    EventDetail.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            moveNext(pathGeometries.get(counter).getX(),
                    pathGeometries.get(counter).getY(), 0, d);
        }
    }, time);
}
```

Comment: It works! But how come to set the time variable as global variable and increment it solve the problem? Do you mind to elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @IWasSoLost with each for loop, you create a new `Runnable` with a `time` variable. That means, each Runnable will have a variable time with value 0. However you need to save the time value and increase it with each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps loop through and use the looping index to build the delay time.

```
for (int iii = 0; iii < pathGeometries.size(); iii++) {
            EventDetail.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    moveNext(pathGeometries.get(counter).getX(),
                            pathGeometries.get(counter).getY(), 0, d);
                }
            }, 1000 *(iii+1)); 
    }
```

Comment: Great! The problem with your code was in scheduling. Each subsequent draw had to be delayed more so that it is done in order. All of them were firing after a span of a second so to speak.